# A really weird .htaccess issue

Tags: html, .htaccess, trailing-slash

So let us say that my website is *www.example.com* and I have a *contact.html* page in the root. The URL normally shown in the address bar is: **http://example.com/contact.html**

For my site, I want the URL to have:

1. no *www*

   no *.html*

   a trailing slash

So the final result should look like this: **http://example.com/contact/**

Condition No. 1 is default, so that doesn't bother me.

For Condition 2 (no '.html'), I have the following code into my .htaccess file place in the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

...and it works perfectly.

Now coming on to Condition 3 (enforcing trailing slash), I have the following code into the .htaccess file **before the 'Condition 2' rewrite commands**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

...this **does not** work; The page redirects to the Error 404 page and the address bar shows: http:/example.com/404.html... YES, with the trailing slash :/

What am I doing wrong?

I have a folder called *archives* in the root directory of which I want indexing to be done. So I simply added a .htaccess file in the 'archives' folder and added the following, simple code:

```
Options +Indexing
```

But it doesn't work; I get redirected to the Error 403 page! I'm 99% sure that it is due the .htaccess file in the *root* directory.

Comment: Please excuse me not answering. When I read a question containing `.htaccess` and "weird", I automatically scan for `RewriteRule` in the question's body. And lo, I _always_ find one. Your question has the unfortunate bad luck to also feature the term "copy-pasted", which really discourages me to craft an answer. I am sorry about that lack of motivation on my part! Perhaps this page will help you further: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/

Comment: Oh, I forgot your additional problem. Sorry about that! The answer is: "yes, the `.htaccess` in the page root is causing that issue."

Comment: I think you are facing this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412585/htaccess-remove-extension-but-allow-404-if-not-existing

Comment: @Boldewyn I used 'copy-pasted' only because I really did, but wisely, of course. Also, what's the solution to the second problem?

Comment: @starkeen Edited the question

Comment: See the linked question.

Comment: Let the `.htaccess` in the root not unconditionally take over requests for missing files (the `!-f` part). E.g., add something like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/archives/.*` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.+) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# remove html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: No, it's not working :(... I'm getting a 404 error, but the address bar does certainly remove the .html and adds a trailing slash

Comment: The real name of your file is `contact.html` (not `contact`) ?

Comment: And I don't remove the `.html` if you use it. Did you clear your cache ?

Comment: I'll try again.

Comment: Nothing changed. Even after clearing the cache. I still get a 404 error...

Comment: In which case (url) are you experiencing the problem?